# How to Rotate Core Text in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, core-graphics, core-text

So I have the following code that rotates the CGContext to position where my text should be:

```
var nums: Int = 0
let oNums: [Int] = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2]

for i in 0..<60 {
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, rect.width / 2, rect.height / 2)
    CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, CGFloat(6.0 * Double(i) * M_PI / 180))
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.grayColor().CGColor)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 72, 0)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 3.0)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, 42, 0)
    drawText(ctx!, text: getRoman(oNums[nums]), attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor().CGColor, NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)], x: 42, y: 0, align: CGFloat(6.0 * Double(i) * M_PI / 180))
    nums++
}
```

Where drawText(_:) is:

```
func drawText(context: CGContextRef, text: NSString, attributes: [String: AnyObject], x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, align: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, 0)
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1)
    let font = attributes[NSFontAttributeName] as! UIFont
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text as String, attributes: attributes)

    let textSize = text.sizeWithAttributes(attributes)

    let textPath    = CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRect(x: x, y: y + font.descender, width: ceil(textSize.width), height: ceil(textSize.height)), nil)
    let frameSetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attributedString)
    let frame       = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(frameSetter, CFRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length), textPath, nil)

    CTFrameDraw(frame, context)

    return textSize
}
```

And getRoman(_:) is:

```
func getRoman(numeral: Int) -> String {switch numeral {case 1:return "I"case 2:return "II"case 3:return "III"case 4:return "IV"case 5:return "V"case 6:return "VI"case 7:return "VII"case 8:return "VIII"case 9:return "IX"case 10:return "X"case 11:return "XI"case 12:return "XII"default:return ""}}
```

The issue, is that this prints text rotated to an angle (the desired result would be text all angled to the same degree (standard text orientation))

Is there a way to rotate Core Text?

Regards, Brandon

Comment: It seems that you are mixing radians with grades.

Comment: I am new to Core Graphics so I'm not quite sure what the problem is.

Comment: I am completely an outsider from ios development, but look at your code. You are dividing pi with 180, which seems like you are mixing radians with grades.

Comment: it would be helpful if you attached an image, showing what you expect it to be and how it appears.

Comment: Lajos: I might be, but I don't think that if the problem. The text is performing the expected behavior, I need to know how to modify it. Ishaq try just setting up a drawRect in a playground (I can't attach right now.)